# missing files blender 2.82 Missing UVs, Textures, detected!

Tags: modeling, sculpt

[image]
Missing UVs, Textures, detected!
Missing UVs, Textures, detected!
Missing UVs, Textures, detected!
Missing UVs, Textures, detected!
the message seems like this, can't use shapes and color pls help urgently. blender 2.82 version
and its look like this pic

Comment: What exactly have you done to get this error message?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. In mode select Single Image instead of Material and you'll see an Add UV button. Just add that and you should be able to paint on the object. If not I'm not sure what else to do. It worked for me. Hope this helped!